# How to keep page scroll location after Onchange event

Tags: scroll, onchange

I am using an onchange event on a dropdown list to update the database, then return back to the same page to display this change.

What I need is for the page to keep the scrolled location rather than the user scrolling back down the page to where the user was working.

Here's the onchange `<select>` tag

```
<option value=''>--Please Select</option>
    <!-- Lots of code not pasted here -->           
</option>
```

Here's the function that is executing

```
function updatePO(poID, trackerID) {
        //this function will add the PO/Vendor chosen from the drop down list on each individual tracker item on the fly
        window.location="https://www.webpage.php?poID="+poID+"&trackerID="+trackerID;
}
```

I've tried various methods from these links but still having trouble incorporating them with my function... Thanks in advance.

[How to maintain page scroll position after a jquery event is carried out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836428/how-to-maintain-page-scroll-position-after-a-jquery-event-is-carried-out)

http://mrcoles.com/blog/scroll-sneak-maintain-position-between-page-loads/

[Refresh Page and Keep Scroll Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642872/refresh-page-and-keep-scroll-position)