# Maintain browsers scroll position on partial postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have update panel and inside that i have drop downs which are doing partial postback.
ASP.NET code for dropdown is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"
UpdateMode="Always">
<asp:CustomDropDownList ID="Review_DropDownList" style="width: 310px;" runat="server" DataTextField="ReviewName" DataValueField="ReviewId" AutoPostBack="True"                   ShowAllItemText='<%$Resources:RATResource,CompanyAllItem %>' ShowAllItemValue=" " EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Review_DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" width="160px"></asp:CustomDropDownList>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

when i am changing drop down browsers scroll is not maintaining the position its automatically going to top.
I have tried `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true` but its not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maintain Panel Scroll Position On Partial Postback ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288682/maintain-panel-scroll-position-on-partial-postback-asp-net)

Comment: Try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/10836745/2174170

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using the sections in your html code, for instance if you are having 3 fold page, then create section for each fold and put all fold in section with # tag, so your URL will have the #section-title which will maintain the scrolling part as it is even after you page post-backs.

Hope this will help..

Cheers!!